# Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll missing dependencies on Win 7 machine

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, dll

I have a C# .Net Office Add-in application (using Add-In Express) that can either access a SQL Server or a VistaDB database, built for .Net 4.5 Any CPU. The Add-In runs OK on a Win 10 box with SQL Server 2014 installed but when it is installed on a Win 7 box with no SQL server it throws an error saying Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll or one of its dependencies is not found. If I run Dependency walker on the Microsoft.SqlServer.dll on the Win 7 box is shows a number of errors:
[image]
On the Win 10 Box Dependency walker on the problem dll shows all the API-MS-WIN-* modules with a yellow question mark beside them but no hourglass and the message "File not found in local directory or search path" to the right of them but no error message and the program runs OK.

No code which involves SQL server is being run by the Add-In but it seems as though the SQL Serve DLLs are accessed anyway and the Add-In is failing.

Is there a way to make the SQL Server Dlls not be accessed unless code is executed on the Win 7 box or to get rid of this error in some other way? C#

Answer (score 1):

The only solution i can think of is to install the SMO dependancies on the client machine. Is this an option? from memory there is a lightweight install required SharedManagementObjects.msi.

Comment: Tried this (SharedManagementObjects.msi also needed SQLSysClrTypes.msi as prerequisite) and running depends.exe on the same Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll shows the same errors. Same errors on the dll appearing in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\SDK\Assemblies.

Comment: A further wrinkle is that the error only occurs when running an Office Add-In (from Office 2016 apps). Calls to the same code appear in a Windows Forms application and are successful.A Google search indicates that Depends.exe may indicate problems where there are none

Comment: Yes i remember now that SQLSysClrTypes.msi was another prerequisite. The implementation i used this in was a winforms app which used SMO to create its own database. Perhaps as you suggest depends.exe may be highlighting problems when there are none and this would still work from the add-in?

Comment: I was able to recode to avoid using the offending dll and now the Add-In works OK on Win 7 with no SQL Server. The Add-In works OK on a Win 7 box with SQL Server installed so it may be a missing pre-requisite that's the problem. Dependency walker shows the same problems on Win7 box with SQL Server

Comment: Yes Dependency Walker shows problems on the Win 10 Dev box where the app runs OK. Looked at ProcessMonitor output too and it shows lots of Unsuccessful statuses including mysterious file accesses but the app runs OK.